# Back button title not receiving previous view controller's title

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am pushing 2 view controllers in to navigation stack in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching.

```
[navigationController pushViewController:favorites animated:NO];
[navigationController pushViewController:root animated:NO];
```

The app loads fine, but on the start screen, the back button title is simply "Back". I do have a title for the FavoritesViewController, and a navigationItem title setup to Favorites.

Am I missing something?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why are you pushing two view controllers? Why not init your navigation controller with a root view controller, ie: initWithRootViewController: and pass your favorites view controller as the root? Also, its not necessarily an error, but your naming is confusing. If root is pushed on top of the favorites, then it's not the root... I don't think you're using the navigation controller properly.

Comment: Thanks Jasarien, 
I just tried it the way you suggested, and I get the same result. Also, if I go back to the favorites view controller and back to root, then it shows Favorites as the backbutton title. Not sure what I am missing here.

Also, regarding the naming, you are right. I must change this. I used to not have the favorites, so it was really the rootViewController. I need to rename the controllers. 

Can you see my problem here at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

The problem was that when the first page was being displayed, the Favorites page is not being initated, and so its title value not displayed. The following code, adds the title value to view controller!

```
NSArray *viewControllerArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
int parentViewControllerIndex = [viewControllerArray count] - 2;
[[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:parentViewControllerIndex] setTitle:@"Favorites"];
```